# World Weather API returns negative swell height

Tags: xml, api, weather

I'm using the World Weather Online API and am getting some funky results. I can't find much documentation about how these readings work, but one weird thing I'm seeing is a swell height of -999 meters. I'm using a location in Mountain View, CA, which isn't super close to water, but I expect that the API will return results from the closest available station/ instruments. Here's an example response:

```
        <data>
        <script id="tinyhippos-injected"/>
        <request>
        <type>LatLon</type>
        <query>Lat 37.39 and Lon -122.09</query>
        </request>
        <nearest_area>
        <latitude>37.467</latitude>
        <longitude>-122.083</longitude>
        <distance_miles>5.4</distance_miles>
        </nearest_area>
        <weather>
        <date>2013-12-06</date>
        <maxtempC>10</maxtempC>
        <mintempC>-233</mintempC>
        <hourly>
        <time>0</time>
        <tempC>1</tempC>
        <tempF>34</tempF>
        <windspeedMiles>4</windspeedMiles>
        <windspeedKmph>6</windspeedKmph>
        <winddirDegree>193</winddirDegree>
        <winddir16Point>SSW</winddir16Point>
        <weatherCode>113</weatherCode>
        <weatherIconUrl>
        <![CDATA[
        http://cdn.worldweatheronline.net/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0001_sunny.png
        ]]>
        </weatherIconUrl>
        <precipMM>0.0</precipMM>
        <humidity>68</humidity>
        <visibility>10</visibility>
        <pressure>1021</pressure>
        <cloudcover>0</cloudcover>
        <sigHeight_m>-999.0</sigHeight_m>
        <swellHeight_m>-999.0</swellHeight_m>
        <swellDir>-999</swellDir>
        <swellPeriod_secs>-999.0</swellPeriod_secs>
        <waterTemp_C>12</waterTemp_C>
        <waterTemp_F>54</waterTemp_F>
        </hourly>
```

Is there some kind of problem with this reading? I'm assuming that it should just be a swell height of zero, which I can deal with, but I want to make sure that -999 doesn't mean something else (like the reading was not available at the time or something).

Comment: Nope, it does that kind of stuff, which is what doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Just sounds like an unreliable service, I know this doesn't answer your question but if this is for a serious application I would look into a pay service. We've been using WeatherUnderground for a little over a year now and it's been great. http://api.wunderground.com/ I'm not 100% sure but I think I read somewhere that Google uses these guys. Also I do believe you can test it out for free.

Comment: Yeah I checked out wunderground, too, but they don't have swell height - according to a forum post from 9 months ago: "
Not right now, only tides. We hope to offer more soon."

Comment: http://api.wunderground.com/weather/api Try this one instead, I just ran a query for Mountain View, CA and got good data. Sorry, I wasn't aware that they didn't have the data you were looking for. I mostly use it for current conditions, forecasts and windspeed, dew point etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-999 is often used to represent missing data in weather feeds, as you feared. If that feed is not giving you the data you want, you might try the [National Data Buoy Center](http://www.ndbc.noaa.gov/), which collects wave height data worldwide with a focus on the US coast. They offer many ways to consume their data including KML download.

Comment: You're absolutely right - I emailed the guys at World Weather and they told me that -999 means they don't have any data for that area. I'll check out National Data Buoy Center and see if they have more robust data available. Thanks!